# Get client computer domain name / MAC

Tags: jsf-2

I'm trying to get the client information in JSF application. But I'm able just to get IP address.

I've tried this:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
System.err.println(request.getRemoteAddr());
System.err.println(request.getRemoteHost());
```

Problem is that `request.getRemoteAddr()` and `request.getRemoteHost()` both gets the IP address.

Is there some way to get client domain name or its MAC address?

**UPDATE (solution):**

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();

String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
if (ipAddress == null) ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr();  // IP

InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);  // DOMAIN NAME from IP
String host = addr.getHostName();
```

Comment: See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteHost()). You will have to do some reverse lookup yourself if you want a name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the domain name, you'll have to do a reverse lookup for the IP yourself. If you want the MAC address, you'll have to resort to magic.

What are you planning to do with that data, and why isn't the IP address enough?

Comment: In a Java EE web application, the Java code runs on webserver, not on webbrowser. If you want to run Java code on webbrowser, you need to embed a Java applet or webstart application in HTML page. That HTML page in turn doesn't necessarily need to be served/generated by Java EE / JSF.